# Why does jquery Isotope work on my local machine but not online

Tags: jquery, wordpress, localhost, mamp, jquery-isotope

On my localhost web server these scripts are loading properly and functioning flawlessly, but on my BlueHost account my console is giving me errors about Isotope having no object.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.isotope.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.infinitescroll.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        var $container = $('#articlePost');


            $container.isotope({
                masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 3}
                });


            $(window).smartresize(function(){
                $container.isotope({
                // update columnWidth to a percentage of container width
                masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 3}
            });

            $container.isotope('reLayout');

    });
});

</script>
```

And here is the Chrome console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'isotope' www.theciv.com:92
(anonymous function) www.theciv.com:92
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.1.js:3074
elemData.handle
```

Comment: There are two versions of jQuery loaded in the page 1.9.1 and 1.8.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two versions of jQuery loaded in the page 1.9.1 and 1.8.3.

One is loaded in the header (1.9.1)

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="http://www.theciv.com/wp-content/themes/toolbox/js/jquery-1.9.1.js" /></script>
```

Another one from wordpress

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.theciv.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3'></script>
```

I think it is the reason, remove one of them and it should work fine

Or make it compatible with jQuery.noConflict()

```
jQuery(function($){
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    var $container = $('#articlePost');

    $container.isotope({
        masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 3}
    });

    $(window).smartresize(function(){
        $container.isotope({
            // update columnWidth to a percentage of container width
            masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 3}
        });

        $container.isotope('reLayout');

    });
});
```

Comment: Ahh! I can't believe I missed that. Well, I removed the extra one so now it's only the Wordpress version of jQuery loading. Unfortunately now I'm getting the classic error that $ is undefined. Would this be because the Wordpress version is too old (1.8....) ? I've heard of some using 'jquery' instead of $, but am unsure if this is a webhost case-by-case issue.

Comment: I think wordpress uses [$.noConflit](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), use jQuery instead of `$` or search for how to prevent it, also see http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16494

Comment: Definitely works! Now to figure out how to convert all of my old $.on('click'... scripts to noConflict...